# Different PDF versions are printing the same information on different coordinates

Tags: java, pdf

I am working on a application where i have to generate a PDF file which eventually gets printed on a specified form. 
I have to be very accurate about the X and Y coordinates of each information on the generated PDF file so that it gets printed on the right places on the targeted form.
My problem is that when i actually prints this PDF file on the required form , the information being printed on different coordinates while printing through different PDF versions. Its a very strange problem for me that why the same generated PDF file gets printed on different X-Y coordinates.
Any idea how i can fix this problem programmatically or its the Problem of Adobe Reader?

Comment: *printing through different PDF versions* - you really mean different PDF versions? Or do you mean different Adobe Reader versions?

Comment: I mean "different Adobe Reader versions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, it should make no difference at all - as you know the PDF coordinate system is extremely well-defined, based on (0, 0) being the bottom left corner of the page.

Here's where things get funny.
When you print, Acrobat is (and when I say 'is' I mean this was true when I worked on it last in 1999) going to make decisions based on the printer/print driver as to how it will print the document.  It's supposed to all come out the same in the wash, but the code goes through different paths depending on if the printer has PostScript (and which version) or is something else.  In the "something else" category, Acrobat has to rasterize the page to print as one big image and how it's rasterized will depend on what the printer is advertising as the real printable area of the page and its nominal resolution.  If Acrobat changed how that information is interpreted (because, say, it was wrong), then the pages will look different.

Here's your real test.  Make a document with a grid on, say, 1 inch or 1/2 inch boundaries, with a mark at say, (36, 36) to orient the corners.  Print that document with both versions of Acrobat and see if they line up (and I'd check with a ruler).  If they line up, then redo the document with text at known locations.  If they still line up, the problem is likely in your code (say, not generating coordinates with enough precision combined with many compound transformations leading to rounding errors).